# display data based on LOV selection in adf

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have adf view Object called **SalesVO** that I need to save to database, in that View object I have a foreign key (CustomerId) that is associated with another View Object called **CustmersVO**
I dragged salesVO in jspx page, The user should enter information in the sales information in the page then click save (commit).

the problem is when while the user is filling the sales info he should select customer from LOV once he select customer the page should display Customer info (like address, phone, ..etc) automatically from CustomersVO

how can I display these read only info of the selected customer?

the structure is as follow:

SalesVO : saleId, SaleDate, **CustomerId** ..... etc

CustomerVO:  **CustomerId**, CustomerName, Phone, Address....etc

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to basically join the Sales info with Customer info and allow user to select the Customer based on Customer ID in Sales VO and then when that customer is selected, display the retrieved customer data along with the sales VO, but only the Sales VO info is saved?

If so this is a simple, basic thing to do in ADF BC.  have you looked at the many tutorials available online [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adfinsider-093342.html)? Have you read the docs on how to create an LOV or Reference entity usage or seen [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/workingwithadf/entry/adf-bc_creating_a_listofvalues_lov_and_a_cascaded_lov) or [this](http://marianne-horsch-adf.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-create-custom-lov.html)?

The SalesVO is based on the Sales EO and is updatable, then add the CustVO as a non-updatable reference only data and then make the Cust ID in the Sales VO the basis for the LOV. The selected Customer data will appear in the LOV and the selected Customer ID will be saved as the foreign key to the Sales VO, with the extra customer data providing non-updatable reference values. The steps to do this are widely available in many blog posts - Google is your friend here. Also consider reading the ADF BC docs, on LOVS, and reference entities and joins of VOs.

Comment: I did it using value Change listener, once I get the CustId from lov I filter the CustomerVO based on it and I get the extra display data.